# What is the reference magnetic field of my iPhone user's location?

Tags: ios, iphone, field, magnetometer

I've been told that Apple ported the World Magnetic Model into their iOS.  The model itself comes from the National Geophysical Data Center, and on their website you can enter your coordinates to get a value (among others) for the intensity of the magnetic field of the Earth at that point.  Can I do this in iOS, or do I need to port the NGDC model to get this reference value?

Please note, I am looking for magnetic field intensity, not direction or declination, and I do not want the user's magnetometer reading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple actually put this into iOS, there is just a third-party app called [World Magnetic Model](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/world-magnetic-model/id349519296?mt=8). Therefore, if you want to use the data, you will probably need the NGDC model. Since that is also available in C you won't have to do much porting. Objective-C is a superset of C, so C code will run just fine in iOS. You just need to take care of the data that goes in and out...

Comment: If you read the Copyright info in the commons menu, you see that apple uses a magnetic geomodell, but I do not remeber which one.